# docker nginx Mount -v

Tags: docker, docker-volume

docker run command error: (I was knocking on the document command, Docker 
version 18.03.0-ce), ask why?

```
docker run -p 80:80 --name mynginx -v $PWD/www:/www -v $PWD/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf -v $PWD/logs:/wwwlogs  -d nginx
```

The error is as follows:

```
ebb97ea2c176cb1693912f54960db6281b30c95482c67df37183a8e1c618ca92
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/home/xiao/nginx/conf/nginx.conf\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/17a9b49be13458de18ce62753d49a94a3d6dc6685af7483f6e9b2e12d20bb92c/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/17a9b49be13458de18ce62753d49a94a3d6dc6685af7483f6e9b2e12d20bb92c/merged/etc/nginx/nginx.conf\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.
```

Comment: `Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)?`

Answer (score 0):

**Problem is due to $PWD/conf/nginx.conf exists in your container**, and command `docker run -p 80:80 --name mynginx -v $PWD/www:/www -v $PWD/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf ...` *is trying to replace nginx.conf in your container with nginx.conf from your host*.

If you want to have a nginx server in your container with your host's nginx.conf configuration, **you have to assure yourself that nginx.conf doesn't exist in container**. 
If it exists in containers because you're installing it in `Dockerfile` and you want to keep in container your host nginx.conf file anyway, you need add `RUN rm -f $PWD/conf/nginx.conf` to your container Dockerfile after nginx installation.

Note that I'm only showing you a possible solution for your proposal, but I cannot recommend you to do it until I know why do you need to use your nginx.conf into the file.